# Adding category in wordpress - custom

Tags: php, wordpress

```
// Auto post ( Unique File Date ).
$postData = array(
    'post_category' => array( '0' ),
    'post_status' => $Post_Status,
    'post_type' => $Post_Type,
    'post_date' => $File_Individual_Date
);
wp_insert_post( $postData );
```

when using `'post_category' => array( '0' ),`, it adds a post under the category `Uncategorised`. What if I have a category in a var lets say:

`$myCategory = 'News'`;

then using `'post_category' => $myCategory` gives error and no new post is added. Is it possible to add categories in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs for [`wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)

`post_category` should be an array of category ID's, so you would need to assign an array of category ID's to your variable for this to work

Comment: ok. it means i can't create a category in this way?. I first need to create a category fron the wp-admin and then choose its id? am i right? @Pieter Goosen

Comment: OK, seems your question is a bit unclear then. You want to assign a category to a post that has not yet been created. You would first then need to create that category before you can assign it to a post. Look at [`wp_insert_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)

Comment: oh so I really need to first create a category from backend(wp-admin) and then assign it to the post. thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$myCategory = array('News');`

UPD: [Just in case](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)

Comment: it adds `—` in the category.

Comment: Looks like you need to use your category id, like $myCategory = array(1)

Comment: you are saying i need to first create a category from backend and then use its id?

Comment: Or you can check the existing category id in the database.